# "MetaClass", "__new__", "cls" and "super" - what is the mechanism exactly?

Tags: python, types, metaclass, super

I have read posts like these:

1. [What is a metaclass in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python)
2. [What are your (concrete) use-cases for metaclasses in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392160/what-are-your-concrete-use-cases-for-metaclasses-in-python)
3. [Python's Super is nifty, but you can't use it](http://fuhm.net/super-harmful/)

But somehow I got confused. Many confusions like:

When and why would I have to do something like the following?

```
# Refer link1
return super(MyType, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, newattrs)
```

or

```
# Refer link2
return super(MetaSingleton, cls).__call__(*args, **kw)
```

or

```
# Refer link2
return type(self.__name__ + other.__name__, (self, other), {})
```

How does super work exactly?

What is class registry and unregistry in link1 and how exactly does it work? (I thought it has something to do with [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). I may be wrong, being from C background. My coding style is still a mix of functional and OO).

What is the flow of class instantiation (subclass, metaclass, super, type) and method invocation (

```
metaclass->__new__, metaclass->__init__, super->__new__, subclass->__init__ inherited from metaclass
```

) with well-commented working code (though the first link is quite close, but it does not talk about cls keyword and super(..) and registry). Preferably an example with  multiple inheritance.

P.S.: I made the last part as code because Stack Overflow formatting was converting the text `metaclass->__new__`
to metaclass->**new**

Answer (score 31, accepted):

OK, you've thrown quite a few concepts into the mix here! I'm going to pull out a few of the specific questions you have.

In general, understanding super, the MRO and metclasses is made much more complicated because there have been lots of changes in this tricky area over the last few versions of Python.

[Python's own documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) is a very good reference, and completely up to date. There is an [IBM developerWorks article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-pymeta.html) which is fine as an introduction and takes a more tutorial-based approach, but note that it's five years old, and spends a lot of time talking about the older-style approaches to meta-classes.

**`super`** is how you access an object's super-classes. It's more complex than (for example) Java's `super` keyword, mainly because of multiple inheritance in Python. As [Super Considered Harmful](http://fuhm.net/super-harmful/) explains, using `super()` can result in you implicitly using a chain of super-classes, the order of which is defined by the [Method Resolution Order](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) (MRO).

You can see the MRO for a class easily by invoking `mro()` on the class (not on an instance). Note that meta-classes are not in an object's super-class hierarchy.

[Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17624/thomas-wouters)' description of meta-classes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python) is excellent:

> A metaclass is the class of a class.
> Like a class defines how an instance
> of the class behaves, a metaclass
> defines how a class behaves. A class
> is an instance of a metaclass.

In the examples you give, here's what's going on:

1. The call to `__new__` is being
   bubbled up to the next thing in the
   MRO. In this case, `super(MyType, cls)` would resolve to `type`;
   calling `type.__new__` lets Python
   complete it's normal instance
   creation steps.
2. This example is using meta-classes
   to enforce a singleton. He's
   overriding `__call__` in the
   metaclass so that whenever a class
   instance is created, he intercepts
   that, and can bypass instance
   creation if there already is one
   (stored in `cls.instance`). Note
   that overriding `__new__` in the
   metaclass won't be good enough,
   because that's only called when
   creating the *class*. Overriding
   `__new__` on the class would work,
   however.
3. This shows a way to dynamically
   create a class. Here's he's
   appending the supplied class's name
   to the created class name, and
   adding it to the class hierarchy
   too.

I'm not exactly sure what sort of code example you're looking for, but here's a brief one showing meta-classes, inheritance and method resolution:

```
print('>>> # Defining classes:')

class MyMeta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        print("meta: creating %s %s" % (name, bases))
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)

    def meta_meth(cls):
        print("MyMeta.meta_meth")

    __repr__ = lambda c: c.__name__

class A(metaclass=MyMeta):
    def __init__(self):
        super(A, self).__init__()
        print("A init")

    def meth(self):
        print("A.meth")

class B(metaclass=MyMeta):
    def __init__(self):
        super(B, self).__init__()
        print("B init")

    def meth(self):
        print("B.meth")

class C(A, B, metaclass=MyMeta):
    def __init__(self):
        super(C, self).__init__()
        print("C init")

print('>>> c_obj = C()')
c_obj = C()
print('>>> c_obj.meth()')
c_obj.meth()
print('>>> C.meta_meth()')
C.meta_meth()
print('>>> c_obj.meta_meth()')
c_obj.meta_meth()
```

Example output (using Python >= 3.6):

```
>>> # Defining classes:
meta: creating A ()
meta: creating B ()
meta: creating C (A, B)
>>> c_obj = C()
B init
A init
C init
>>> c_obj.meth()
A.meth
>>> C.meta_meth()
MyMeta.meta_meth
>>> c_obj.meta_meth()
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "metatest.py", line 41, in <module>
    c_obj.meta_meth()
AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute 'meta_meth'
```

Comment: Thanks. Registry and MetaSingleton - are just some names from the link (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python)i mentioned, the context is in code there. This does not answer all questions, I'll wait for a few more answers before I revert back on any.

Comment: Ah, I see - I didn't understand what the #first link and #second link comments meant. I've added explanations for the samples now that I can see them in context.

Comment: Thanks again. I have edited my question to make link references explicit.

Comment: `type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)`: What is `name`, `bases` and `dct`?

Comment: Found them: https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation

Comment: And they are arguments of [`type(name, bases, dict)`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#type).

Answer (score 10):

Here's the more pragmatic answer.

**It rarely matters**

1. "[What is a metaclass in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python)".  Bottom line, `type` is the metaclass of all classes.  You have almost no practical use for this.

   ```
   class X(object):
       pass
   type(X) == type
   ```
2. "[What are your (concrete) use cases for metaclasses in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392160/what-are-your-concrete-use-cases-for-metaclasses-in-python)".  Bottom line.  None.
3. "[Python's Super is nifty, but you can't use it](http://fuhm.net/super-harmful/)".  Interesting note, but little practical value.  You'll never have a need for resolving complex multiple inheritance networks.  It's easy to prevent this problem from arising by using an explicity **Strategy** design instead of multiple inheritance.

Here's my experience over the last 7 years of Python programming.

1. A class has 1 or more superclasses forming a simple chain from my class to `object`.
2. The concept of "class" is defined by a metaclass named `type`.  I might want to extend the concept of "class", but so far, it's never come up in practice.  Not once.  `type` always does the right thing.
3. Using `super` works out really well in practice.  It allows a subclass to defer to it's superclass.  It happens to show up in these metaclass examples because they're extending the built-in metaclass, `type`.

   However, in all subclass situations, you'll make use of `super` to extend a superclass.

**Metaclasses**

The metaclass issue is this:

- Every object has a reference to it's type definition, or "class".
- A `class` is, itself, also an object.
- Therefore a object of type `class` has a reference to it's type or "class".  The "class" of a "class" is a metaclass.

Since a "class" isn't a C++ run-time object, this doesn't happen in C++.  It does happen in Java, Smalltalk and Python.

A metaclass defines the behavior of a class object.

- 90% of your interaction with a class is to ask the class to create a new object.
- 10% of the time, you'll be using class methods or class variables ("static" in C++ or Java parlance.)

I have found a few use cases for class-level methods.  I have almost no use cases for class variables.  I've never had a situation to change the way object construction works.

Comment: Perhaps I should have added that the real-world uses of meta-classes are few and far between, I definitely agree with that! The notable exceptions do justify meta-classes existence, however.

Comment: On multiple inheritance, I disagree. A simple chain of stand-alones up to object is good design IMO, but mix-ins are great and I'd encourage their use when appropriate. And as soon as you use mix-ins, you really do need to understand the MRO to make sure you don't shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: @jamesbrady: metaclasses have to exist; no issue there.  Do they have to be deeply understood?  Not really.

Comment: @jamesbrady: as soon as you need to understand MRO, you've made a mistake.  I use mixins without any MRO issues because I design the mixins to be very simple.

Comment: @S.Lott: I think a decent understanding of the MRO and super is a very valuable tool. Without being aware of the nastiness that multiple inheritance *can* leave you with, we wouldn't know why linear inheritance chains, simple mix-ins and so on are desirable. Knowing the wrong option is still useful!

Comment: @jamesbrady: My answer is based on my experience: it so rarely comes up in practice that I don't see any value in deep understanding.  A superficial summary is all anyone needs.  That's why I posted my answer.

Comment: @S.Lott: 
1. "It rarely matters" - can you elicit the rare cases
2. "Do they have to be deeply understood?"- why not? atleast for the curiosity part of it, even if one can't find more than a handful use cases. 
3.I agree with Strategy design part of it but using MRO as a cross check is fine I guess.

Comment: @JV: I have never used a metaclass and never will.  For me, it does not matter.  I say "rarely" because I have seen it used, for example, in Django.  Read their models module for an example.

Comment: @JV: "why not deeply understand this?"  Deep understanding should be reserved for end users' use cases.  Edge-of-the-envelope language features need a just-enough understanding.

Comment: What he is saying is we are all sheep and need to get in line. Don't worry, you don't need to know that. It is too hard for you. The more _you_ know the less secure _his_ job is. **Screw that.** Learn as much as you want about the languages you use and don't let these (python) indoctrinators tell you what you need to know. Peace.

Comment: @hiwaylon: "all sheep and need to get in line"?  Really?  I thought I said it was rarely needed.  "Learn as much as you want about the languages you use".  Didn't I suggest specifically looking at Django for one good example?  Why all the anger?

Comment: About use cases: When you're working with frameworks (such as django and django-cms) they may work with *different underlying infrastructure*. What one understands under "Plugin" is different to what the other understands. And *this requires two classes* out of a single definition.