# Using the __call__ method of a metaclass instead of __new__?

Tags: python, oop, metaclass

When discussing metaclasses, [the docs](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) state:

> You can of course also override other class methods (or add new
> methods); for example defining a custom `__call__()` method in the
> metaclass allows custom behavior when the class is called, e.g. not
> always creating a new instance.

*[Editor's note: This was removed from the docs in 3.3. It's here in 3.2: [Customizing class creation](https://docs.python.org/3.2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation)]*

My questions is: suppose I want to have custom behavior when the class is called, for example caching instead of creating fresh objects. I can do this by overriding the `__new__` method of the class. When would I want to define a metaclass with `__call__` instead? What does this approach give that isn't achievable with `__new__`?

Comment: for anyone going in the docs, the statement is unfortunately no where to be found.

Comment: @Marine It was removed in 3.3. Here it is in 3.2: [Customizing class creation](https://docs.python.org/3.2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-class-creation)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is: when you want to do **more** than just customize instance creation, or when you want to separate what the class **does** from how it's created.

See my answer to [Creating a singleton in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python) and the associated discussion.

There are several advantages.

1. It allows you to separate what the class *does* from the details of how it's created. The metaclass and class are each responsible for one thing.
2. You can write the code once in a metaclass, and use it for customizing several classes' call behavior without worrying about multiple inheritance.
3. Subclasses can override behavior in their `__new__` method, but `__call__` on a metaclass doesn't have to even call `__new__` at all.
4. If there is setup work, you can do it in the `__new__` method of the metaclass, and it only happens once, instead of every time the class is called.

There are certainly lots of cases where customizing `__new__` works just as well if you're not worried about the single responsibility principle.

But there are other use cases that have to happen earlier, when the class is created, rather than when the instance is created. It's when these come in to play that a metaclass is necessary. See [What are your (concrete) use-cases for metaclasses in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392160/what-are-your-concrete-use-cases-for-metaclasses-in-python) for lots of great examples.

Answer (score 44):

The subtle differences become a bit more visible when you carefully observe the execution order of these methods.

```
class Meta_1(type):
    def __call__(cls, *a, **kw):
        print "entering Meta_1.__call__()"
        rv = super(Meta_1, cls).__call__(*a, **kw)
        print "exiting Meta_1.__call__()"
        return rv

class Class_1(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta_1
    def __new__(cls, *a, **kw):
        print "entering Class_1.__new__()"
        rv = super(Class_1, cls).__new__(cls, *a, **kw)
        print "exiting Class_1.__new__()"
        return rv

    def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
        print "executing Class_1.__init__()"
        super(Class_1,self).__init__(*a, **kw)
```

Note that the code above doesn't actually *do* anything other than log what we're doing. Each method defers to its parent implementation i.e. its default. So beside logging it's effectively as if you had simply declared things as follows:

```
class Meta_1(type): pass
class Class_1(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta_1
```

And now let's create an instance of `Class_1`

```
c = Class_1()
# entering Meta_1.__call__()
# entering Class_1.__new__()
# exiting Class_1.__new__()
# executing Class_1.__init__()
# exiting Meta_1.__call__()
```

Therefore if `type` is the parent of `Meta_1` we can imagine a pseudo implementation of `type.__call__()` as such:

```
class type:
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwarg):

        # ... a few things could possibly be done to cls here... maybe... or maybe not...

        # then we call cls.__new__() to get a new object
        obj = cls.__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

        # ... a few things done to obj here... maybe... or not...

        # then we call obj.__init__()
        obj.__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # ... maybe a few more things done to obj here

        # then we return obj
        return obj
```

Notice from the call order above that `Meta_1.__call__()` (or in this case `type.__call__()`) is given the opportunity to influence whether or not calls to `Class_1.__new__()` and `Class_1.__init__()` are eventually made. Over the course of its execution `Meta_1.__call__()` could return an object that hasn't even been touched by either. Take for example this approach to the singleton pattern:

```
class Meta_2(type):
    __Class_2_singleton__ = None
    def __call__(cls, *a, **kw):
        # if the singleton isn't present, create and register it
        if not Meta_2.__Class_2_singleton__:
            print "entering Meta_2.__call__()"
            Meta_2.__Class_2_singleton__ = super(Meta_2, cls).__call__(*a, **kw)
            print "exiting Meta_2.__call__()"
        else:
            print ("Class_2 singleton returning from Meta_2.__call__(), "
                    "super(Meta_2, cls).__call__() skipped")
        # return singleton instance
        return Meta_2.__Class_2_singleton__

class Class_2(object):
    __metaclass__ = Meta_2
    def __new__(cls, *a, **kw):
        print "entering Class_2.__new__()"
        rv = super(Class_2, cls).__new__(cls, *a, **kw)
        print "exiting Class_2.__new__()"
        return rv

    def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
        print "executing Class_2.__init__()"
        super(Class_2, self).__init__(*a, **kw)
```

Let's observe what happens when repeatedly trying to create an object of type `Class_2`

```
a = Class_2()
# entering Meta_2.__call__()
# entering Class_2.__new__()
# exiting Class_2.__new__()
# executing Class_2.__init__()
# exiting Meta_2.__call__()

b = Class_2()
# Class_2 singleton returning from Meta_2.__call__(), super(Meta_2, cls).__call__() skipped

c = Class_2()
# Class_2 singleton returning from Meta_2.__call__(), super(Meta_2, cls).__call__() skipped

print a is b is c
True
```

Now observe this implementation using a class' `__new__()` method to try to accomplish the same thing.

```
import random
class Class_3(object):

    __Class_3_singleton__ = None

    def __new__(cls, *a, **kw):
        # if singleton not present create and save it
        if not Class_3.__Class_3_singleton__:
            print "entering Class_3.__new__()"
            Class_3.__Class_3_singleton__ = rv = super(Class_3, cls).__new__(cls, *a, **kw)
            rv.random1 = random.random()
            rv.random2 = random.random()
            print "exiting Class_3.__new__()"
        else:
            print ("Class_3 singleton returning from Class_3.__new__(), "
                   "super(Class_3, cls).__new__() skipped")

        return Class_3.__Class_3_singleton__ 

    def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
        print "executing Class_3.__init__()"
        print "random1 is still {random1}".format(random1=self.random1)
        # unfortunately if self.__init__() has some property altering actions
        # they will affect our singleton each time we try to create an instance 
        self.random2 = random.random()
        print "random2 is now {random2}".format(random2=self.random2)
        super(Class_3, self).__init__(*a, **kw)
```

Notice that the above implementation even though successfully registering a singleton on the class, does not prevent `__init__()` from being called, this happens implicitly in `type.__call__()` (`type` being the default metaclass if none is specified). This could lead to some undesired effects:

```
a = Class_3()
# entering Class_3.__new__()
# exiting Class_3.__new__()
# executing Class_3.__init__()
# random1 is still 0.282724600824
# random2 is now 0.739298365475

b = Class_3()
# Class_3 singleton returning from Class_3.__new__(), super(Class_3, cls).__new__() skipped
# executing Class_3.__init__()
# random1 is still 0.282724600824
# random2 is now 0.247361634396

c = Class_3()
# Class_3 singleton returning from Class_3.__new__(), super(Class_3, cls).__new__() skipped
# executing Class_3.__init__()
# random1 is still 0.282724600824
# random2 is now 0.436144427555

d = Class_3()
# Class_3 singleton returning from Class_3.__new__(), super(Class_3, cls).__new__() skipped
# executing Class_3.__init__()
# random1 is still 0.282724600824
# random2 is now 0.167298405242

print a is b is c is d
# True
```

Comment: This is a great answer. In your `Meta_1.__call__`, you have `rv = super(Meta_1, cls).__call__(*a, **kw)`.  Can you explain why `Meta_1 ` is the first argument in `super` ??

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I've used part of the sample code and asked a specific question that I was confused about. I feel much better on this topic now. For your reference the question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56691487/how-does-metaclass-work-with-the-mro-list-when-super-is-called?noredirect=1#comment99954766_56691487

Comment: Do you mind if I paraphrase your comments and post as an answer to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56691487/how-does-metaclass-work-with-the-mro-list-when-super-is-called?noredirect=1 ??  Or even better, do you mind spending a minute to copy your comments here and paste as answer to the linked question?  I'll give upvotes for sure.

Comment: So, I thought that `super(arg1, arg2)` will look into the MRO of the second input argument to find the first input argument, and return the next class to it. But `rv = super(Meta_1, cls).__call__(*a, **kw)`, the MRO for 2nd argument(`cls`, or `Class_1 `), does not contain the 1st input argument(`Meta_1`), you cannot find `Meta_1` in the MRO for `Class_1`. so I didn't see why would it take us to invoke `type.__call__(Class_1)`.  That's why I asked.

Answer (score 19):

One difference is that by defining a metaclass `__call__` method you are demanding that it gets called before any of the class's or subclasses's `__new__` methods get an opportunity to be called.

```
class MetaFoo(type):
    def __call__(cls,*args,**kwargs):
        print('MetaFoo: {c},{a},{k}'.format(c=cls,a=args,k=kwargs))

class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__=MetaFoo

class SubFoo(Foo):
    def __new__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        # This never gets called
        print('Foo.__new__: {a},{k}'.format(a=args,k=kwargs))

 sub=SubFoo()
 foo=Foo()

 # MetaFoo: <class '__main__.SubFoo'>, (),{}
 # MetaFoo: <class '__main__.Foo'>, (),{}
```

Notice that `SubFoo.__new__` never gets called. In contrast, if you define `Foo.__new__` without a metaclass, you allow subclasses to override `Foo.__new__`.

Of course, you could define `MetaFoo.__call__` to call `cls.__new__`, but that's up to you. By refusing to do so, you can prevent subclasses from having their `__new__` method called.

I don't see a compelling advantage to using a metaclass here. And since "Simple is better than complex", I'd recommend using `__new__`.

Comment: Note also that `cls.__new__()` will get called indirectly if the `MetaFoo.__call__()` method invokes `super(MetaFoo, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)`.

Comment: btw, the __metaclass__ attribute is gone in python3, use `class Simple1(object, metaclass = SimpleMeta1):` now... gee thanks https://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Metaprogramming.html#the-metaclass-hook-in-python-3

Answer (score 13):

I thought a fleshed out Python 3 version of pyroscope's answer might be handy for someone to copy, paste and hack about with (probably me, when I find myself back at this page looking it up again in 6 months). It is taken from [this article](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/):

```
class Meta(type):

     @classmethod
     def __prepare__(mcs, name, bases, **kwargs):
         print('  Meta.__prepare__(mcs=%s, name=%r, bases=%s, **%s)' % (
             mcs, name, bases, kwargs
         ))
         return {}

     def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs, **kwargs):
         print('  Meta.__new__(mcs=%s, name=%r, bases=%s, attrs=[%s], **%s)' % (
             mcs, name, bases, ', '.join(attrs), kwargs
         ))
         return super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)

     def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs, **kwargs):
         print('  Meta.__init__(cls=%s, name=%r, bases=%s, attrs=[%s], **%s)' % (
             cls, name, bases, ', '.join(attrs), kwargs
         ))
         super().__init__(name, bases, attrs)

     def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
         print('  Meta.__call__(cls=%s, args=%s, kwargs=%s)' % (
             cls, args, kwargs
         ))
         return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)

print('** Meta class declared')

class Class(metaclass=Meta, extra=1):

     def __new__(cls, myarg):
         print('  Class.__new__(cls=%s, myarg=%s)' % (
             cls, myarg
         ))
         return super().__new__(cls)

     def __init__(self, myarg):
         print('  Class.__init__(self=%s, myarg=%s)' % (
             self, myarg
         ))
         self.myarg = myarg
         super().__init__()

     def __str__(self):
         return "<instance of Class; myargs=%s>" % (
             getattr(self, 'myarg', 'MISSING'),
         )

print('** Class declared')

Class(1)
print('** Class instantiated')
```

Outputs:

```
** Meta class declared
  Meta.__prepare__(mcs=<class '__main__.Meta'>, name='Class', bases=(), **{'extra': 1})
  Meta.__new__(mcs=<class '__main__.Meta'>, name='Class', bases=(), attrs=[__module__, __qualname__, __new__, __init__, __str__, __classcell__], **{'extra': 1})
  Meta.__init__(cls=<class '__main__.Class'>, name='Class', bases=(), attrs=[__module__, __qualname__, __new__, __init__, __str__, __classcell__], **{'extra': 1})
** Class declared
  Meta.__call__(cls=<class '__main__.Class'>, args=(1,), kwargs={})
  Class.__new__(cls=<class '__main__.Class'>, myarg=1)
  Class.__init__(self=<instance of Class; myargs=MISSING>, myarg=1)
** Class instantiated
```

Another great resource highlighted by the same article is David Beazley's PyCon 2013 [Python 3 Metaprogramming tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sPiWg5jSoZI).

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of lifecycle phases and what you have access to. `__call__` gets called *after* `__new__` and is passed the initialization parameters *before* they get passed on to `__init__`, so you can manipulate them. Try this code and study its output:

```
class Meta(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, newattrs):
        print "new: %r %r %r %r" % (cls, name, bases, newattrs,)
        return super(Meta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, newattrs)

    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        print "call: %r %r %r" % (self, args, kw)
        return super(Meta, self).__call__(*args, **kw)

class Foo:
    __metaclass__ = Meta

    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        print "init: %r %r %r" % (self, args, kw)

f = Foo('bar')
print "main: %r" % f
```

Comment: No! `__new__` on the metaclass happens when the _class_ is created, not an _instance_. `__call__` happens when `__new__` would happen without the metaclass.

Comment: Where do I say that `__new__` is related to instance creation?

Comment: I was actually asking about the class's `__new__`, not the metaclass's `__new__`.

Comment: It certainly sounds like you're talking about the class' `__new__` there rather than the metaclass `__new__`.

Comment: `__new__` of a class (not metaclass) is called when the object is created at instantiation of the class. It is useful if you want to return an object that has been created before (e.g. a singleton).instead of re-creating a new object.

Comment: This answer is relevant and gets straight to the point imo. A register pattern would seem to fit most naturally in a metaclass, as other answers suggest, so I'd also assumed the OP was asking about the metaclass `__new__()`. Sometimes you might also need the metaclass `__prepare__` method to intervene even earlier in instantiation. [This post](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2015/02/09/understanding-python-metaclasses/) is a pretty good overview, although it could do with an applied example.

Answer (score 0):

In the particular example given in the question, overriding `__call__` in the **metaclass is just superior** to overriding `__new__` in the class.

> suppose I want to have custom behavior when the class is called, for example **caching instead of creating fresh objects**

1. If the purpose of caching is efficiency, then caching `__new__`'s result is **not optimal** because `__init__` is executed anyhow ([Data Model: Basic Customization](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization)). For example:

   ```
   from functools import lru_cache

   class MyClass:

       @lru_cache(maxsize=None)
       def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
           return super().__new__(cls)

       def __init__(self, ...)
           "Always executed. Even on cache hit."
   ```
2. Caching `__new__`'s result is **sound only if** `__init__` has no noticeable effect on an already initialized instance. *Otherwise* the execution of `__init__` on a cached object could lead to **annoying side-effects** on its other references.
3. Caching at the metaclass level avoids both the performance issue of 1. and the correctness issue of 2. For example:

   ```
   from functools import lru_cache

   class CachedInstances(type):

       @lru_cache(maxsize=None)
       def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
           return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)

   class MyClass(metaclass=CachedInstances):

       def __init__(self, ...)
           "Only executed on cache miss."
   ```

*Note that Michael Ekoka's answer already mention undesired effects that may arise due to repeated `__init__` execution within the override `__new__` approach (as in my item 2).*