# When (and why) was Python `__new__()` introduced?

Tags: python, oop, python-2.x

When (and why) was the Python `__new__()` function introduced?

There are three steps in creating an instance of a class, e.g. `MyClass()`:

- `MyClass.__call__()` is called. This method must be defined in the metaclass of `MyClass`.
- `MyClass.__new__()` is called (by `__call__`). Defined on `MyClass` itself. This creates the instance.
- `MyClass.__init__()` is called (also by `__call__`). This initializes the instance.

Creation of the instance can be influenced either by overloading `__call__` or `__new__`. There usually is little reason to overload `__call__` instead of `__new__` (e.g. [Using the __call__ method of a metaclass instead of __new__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966772/using-the-call-method-of-a-metaclass-instead-of-new)).

We have some old code (still running strong!) where `__call__` is overloaded. The reason given was that `__new__` was not available at the time. So I tried to learn more about the history of both Python and our code, but I could not figure out when `__new__` was introduced.

`__new__` appears in the [documentation for Python 2.4](https://docs.python.org/2.4/ref/customization.html) and not in those for [Python 2.3](https://docs.python.org/2.3/ref/customization.html), but it does not appear in the [whathsnew](https://docs.python.org/2/whatsnew/2.4.html) of any of the Python 2 versions. The [first commit that introduced `__new__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/6d6c1a35e08b95a83dbe47dbd9e6474daff00354) (Merge of descr-branch back into trunk.) that I could find is from 2001, but the 'back into trunk' message is an indication that there was something before. [PEP 252 (Making Types Look More Like Classes)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0252/) and [PEP 253 (Subtyping Built-in Types)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0253/) from a few months earlier seem to be relevant.

Learning more about the introduction of `__new__` would teach us more about why Python is the way it is.

---

Edit for clarification:

It seems that `class.__new__` duplicates functionality that is already provided by `metaclass.__call__`. It seems un-Pythonic to add a method only to replicate existing functionality in a better way.

`__new__` is one of the few class methods that you get out of the box (i.e. with `cls` as first argument), thereby introducing complexity that wasn't there before. If the class is the first argument of a function, then it can be argued that the function should be a normal method of the metaclass. But that method did already exist: `__call__()`. I feel like I'm missing something.

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

Comment: You say that introducing `__new__` violates the rule "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it." from Zen of Python. But there is another one: "Although practicality beats purity.". Introducing a method that is easier to write and more understandable to read, that doesn't require you to write a metaclass, is a practical decision that beats the purity of "one way to do it". That's why I can say it is Pythonic to have `__new__`.

Comment: Is that just it @Sanyash, 'practicality beats purity'? I'm not so convinced that the extra complexity actually makes things that much more practical. `__new__` indeed allows one to do metaclass-stuff without actually using metaclasses. Not sure it's worth it though: you're in quite deep when you're using `__new__`, so you might as well use metaclasses directly. You're probably right though.

Comment: @BlackShift: Added a response to your edit in the answer.

Comment: I see `__new__` mentioned in [the documentation of Python 2.2](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/#__new__), which is the version that introduced new-style classes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The blog post [**`The Inside Story on New-Style Classes`**](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/inside-story-on-new-style-classes.html) 
(from the aptly named **`http://python-history.blogspot.com`**) written by [**`Guido van Rossum`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guido_van_Rossum) (Python's BDFL) provides some good information regarding this subject.

Some relevant quotes:

> New-style classes introduced a new class method `__new__()` that lets
>   the class author customize how new class instances are created. By
>   overriding `__new__()` a class author can implement patterns like the
>   Singleton Pattern, return a previously created instance (e.g., from a
>   free list), or to return an instance of a different class (e.g., a
>   subclass). However, the use of `__new__` has other important
>   applications. For example, in the pickle module, `__new__` is used to
>   create instances when unserializing objects. In this case, instances
>   are created, but the `__init__` method is not invoked.
>
> Another use of `__new__` is to help with the subclassing of immutable
>   types. By the nature of their immutability, these kinds of objects can
>   not be initialized through a standard `__init__()` method. Instead, any
>   kind of special initialization must be performed as the object is
>   created; for instance, if the class wanted to modify the value being
>   stored in the immutable object, the `__new__` method can do this by
>   passing the modified value to the base class `__new__` method.

You can read the entire post for more information on this subject.

Another post about [**`New-style Classes`**](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2010/06/new-style-classes.html) which was written along with the above quoted post has some additional information.

**Edit:**

In response to OP's edit and the quote from the Zen of Python, I would say this.
[Zen of Python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) was not written by the creator of the language but by Tim Peters and was published only in August 19, 2004. We have to take into account the fact that `__new__` appears only in the documentation of Python 2.4 (which was released on [November 30, 2004](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Python)), and this particular guideline (or aphorism) did not even exist **publicly** when `__new__` was introduced into the language.

Even if such a document of guidelines existed *informally* before, I do not think that the author(s) intended them to be misinterpreted as a design document for an entire language and ecosystem.

Comment: These posts, while insightful, do not really address why `class.__new__` was introduced when `metaclass.__call__` already offered all the functionality described in the blog. It seems un-Pythonic to introduce a whole new method only to replicate existing functionality in a slightly better way. I feel like I'm missing something from the picture.

Comment: @BlackShift: The post only mentions three use cases of `__new__`. As per the post there are other important applications which are not listed. Do you say it is un-Pythonic because there should not be more than one way of getting things done in Python?

Comment: Thanks for the edit @P.W, that timeline and @Sanyash' comment explains the introduction of `__new__` well enough. I was hoping there would be some new functionality with `__new__`, e.g. something that couldn't already be done with `__call__`, that I wasn't yet aware off.

Answer (score 5):

I will not explain the history of `__new__` here because I have only used Python since 2005, so after it was introduced into the language. But here is the rationale behind it.

The *normal* configuration method for a new object is the `__init__` method of its class. The object has already been created (usually via an indirect call to `object.__new__`) and the method just *initializes* it. Simply, if you have a truely non mutable object, it is too late.

In that use case the Pythonic way is the `__new__` method, which builds and returns the new object. The nice point with it, is that is is still included in the class definition and does not require a specific metaclass. Standard documentation states:

> **new**() is intended mainly to allow subclasses of immutable types (like int, str, or tuple) to customize instance creation. It is also commonly overridden in custom metaclasses in order to customize class creation.

Defining a `__call__` method on the metaclass is indeed allowed but is IMHO non Pythonic, because `__new__` should be enough. In addition, `__init__`, `__new__` and metaclasses each dig deeper inside the internal Python machinery. So the rule shoud be *do not use `__new__` if `__init__` is enough, and do not use metaclasses if `__new__` is enough*.

Comment: Agreed, nowadays `__new__` should be used instead of `__call__`. It is the introduction of `__new__` itself that seems un-Pythonic though. "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it." So why add `class.__new__` if `metaclass.__call__` already fits the bill? E.g. it is one of the few static methods out-of-the-box (the only one?), thereby adding cognitive complexity.