# how does metaclass work with the MRO list when super() is called?

Tags: python, super, metaclass, method-resolution-order

I'm really confused by the following code sample:

```
class Meta_1(type):
    def __call__(cls, *a, **kw):             # line 1
        print("entering Meta_1.__call__()")  

        print(cls)                           # line 4
        print(cls.mro())                     # line 5
        print(super(Meta_1, cls).__self__)   # line 6

        rv = super(Meta_1, cls).__call__(*a, **kw)  # line 7
        print("exiting Meta_1.__call__()")
        return rv


class Car(object, metaclass=Meta_1):

    def __new__(cls, *a, **kw):
        print("Car.__new__()")
        rv = super(Car, cls).__new__(cls, *a, **kw)
        return rv

    def __init__(self, *a, **kw):
        print("Car.__init__()")
        super(Car,self).__init__(*a, **kw)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    c = Car()
```

The print message for this code is:

```
entering Meta_1.__call__()
<class '__main__.Car'>                      # line 4
[<class '__main__.Car'>, <class 'object'>]  # line 5
<class '__main__.Car'>                      # line 6
Car.__new__()
Car.__init__()
exiting Meta_1.__call__()
```

<s>The result shows that `cls` of line 4 is the `Car` class and its MRO list is: 

 `[<class '__main__.Car'>, <class 'object'>]`</s>

However, line 6 shows that `super(Meta_1, cls).__self__` is also the `Car` class.

I am really confused that:

1. In line 7, It seems that `super(Meta_1, cls).__call__(*a, **kw)` eventually lead to `type.__call__`. 
   But, to my knowledge, `super(arg1, arg2)` will look into the MRO of the second input argument to find the first input argument, and return the next class to it. But in line 6 and 7 of my code, the MRO for 2nd argument(`Car`), does not contain the 1st input argument(`Meta_1`), you cannot find `Meta_1` in the MRO for `Car`. so why would `super(Meta_1, cos)` take us to invoke `type.__call__` ??

<s>2. if `super(Meta_1, cls).__self__` is the `Car` class, then line 7 means it's `Car`'s `__call__` that's being called?  But calling the `Car` class took us to line 1 in the first place, right? wouldn't that be a loop?</s>

Comment: `__call__` is an instance method of `Meta_1`, and `Car` is an instance of `Meta_1`. That means `Car()` is really short for `Meta_1.__call__(Car)`.

Comment: `Meta_1` is not in the MRO of `cls` for the same reason that `type` is not in the MRO of an "ordinary" class.

Comment: @chepner Thank you. Then why should we put `Meta_1` as the first argument in `super()`?

Comment: Because that call is part of the definition of `Meta_1.__call__`. It's the same reason you use `super(Car, self).__init__` in `Car.__init__`.

Comment: @chepner  I'm still confused. The definition of `Meta_1.__call__` is line 1, right? how does that relates to `super()` function?

Comment: The purpose of `type.__call__` (which you are overriding in `Meta_1`) is to ensure that the class's `__new__` method gets called, so that you can write `Car()` instead of `Car.__new__()`. Using `super().__call__` ensures that `type.__call__` (eventually) gets called rather than you having to invoke `cls.__new__` yourself.

Comment: @chepner  so `super(Meta_1, cls).__call__(*a, **kw)` in line 7 basically invokes `type.__call__`, which then executes `Car`'s `__new__`, is that accurate? This makes very good sense. I just don't see how `super(Meta_1, cls)` leads us to `type`.

Comment: Because `type` is in the MRO of `Meta_1`.

Comment: @chepner   I understand type is in the MRO for Meta_1, but in my code above, we are dealing with the MRO for `cos` (which is `Car`), and it does not contain `Meta_1`, right?

Comment: @chepner  my question is simple:  `super()` will look into the MRO of the second input argument to find the first input argument, and return the next class to it. But in my case, the MRO for 2nd argument, a.k.a `Car`, does not contain the 1st input argument, a.k.a. `Meta_1`, you cannot find `Meta_1` in the MRO for `Car`. so why would `super(Meta_1, cls)` take us to `type.__call__` ??

Comment: `super(Meta_1, cls)` does not use `cls.mro()`. `Meta_1` is not in the MRO for `Car`, because `Car` does not inherit from `Meta_1`.

Comment: @chepner Isn't it true that super() will look into the MRO of the second input argument to find the first input argument, and return the next class to it?

Comment: The `mro` method returns the MRO that is used for *instances* of the class. The wording is tricky, but `cls.mro()` returns the list of classes that get checked for *instances* of `cls`.

Comment: @chepner  whose MRO does `super(Meta_1, cls)` use?  `Meta_1 `'s MRO?

Comment: In theory; as far as I can tell, though, that's all special-cased in the implementation and not explicitly visible in Python itself.

Comment: @chepner  So, usually `super(A, B)` would use `B`'s MRO, but in my case in line 6 and 7, `super(A, B)` actually uses `A`'s MRO. We don't know why. The logic behind it remains a mystery.  oh that's frustrating.

Comment: `B` doesn't have an MRO if it's not a type; `type(B)` does. There is no mystery here, only possibly confusion because `cls` (like any object) *has* a type, but also *is* a type. You need to be clear about what role `cls` is playing before you can think about which MRO is applicable. When `cls` is the *second* argument, you use the MRO determined by its type; when it is the *first* argument, you use the MRO determined by the type of the second argument (which is, very often, the first argument).

Comment: Excellent answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966772/using-the-call-method-of-a-metaclass-instead-of-new/39363704?noredirect=1#comment100012101_39363704

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing a few concepts. The first of them is confusing the Metaclass with the class inheritance hierarchy.

Both things are ortogonal - looking at `Car`'s mro will show you the inheritance tree for that class, and that does not include the metaclass. In other words, no `Meta_1` should not, by any means, be in the MRO (or inheritance Tree).

The metaclass is the class' type - that is, it has the templates and methods to create the class object itself. As such, it has the "mechanisms" to build the class MRO itself, and to call the class' `__new__` and `__init__` (and `__init_subclass__` and initialize the descriptors calling their `__set_name__`).

So, calling a class object, as calling any instance in Python will run the code in it's class `__call__` method. In the case of a class, it happens that "calling" the class is the way to create a new instance - and what does that is the metaclass' `__call__`.

The other thing you are misunderstanding there is the `super()` object. `Super()` is not actually the superclass, neither an instance of the superclass - it is rather a proxy object, that will relay any attribute retrieval or method call to methods and attributes on the proper superclass. As part ot the mechanism `super()` uses to be able to act as a proxy, is to have the *instance* where it is called as its own `__self__` attribute. In other words, the `__self__`  attribute is an ordinary attribute on the (proxy) object returned by `super()` call - it is picked from the second argument, or automatically in Python 3 - and it is used internally when the `super` object is used as a proxy to get act as if it were accessing attributes or methods on the "superclass" of that instance. (The instance annotated in `__self__`).

When you use  `super()` inside the metaclass, the class proxied is the metaclass's superclass, which is  `type`, not Car's superclass, `object`.

And so to yours second question:

> 2. if `super(Meta_1, cls).__self__` is the Car class, then line 7 means it's Car's `__call__` that's being called? But calling the Car
>      class took us to line 1 in the first place, right? wouldn't that be a
>      loop?

As said above, the `super()` call from the metaclass' `__call__` will call `type.__call__`, and it will get the class `Car` as its `cls` parameter. That method in turn, will run `Car.__new__`  and `Car.__init__` as the normal process to instantiate the class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. On this sentence you say about `super`:  "....And one of the things it has to be able to do that is to anotate the instance where it is called from in its own `__self__` attribute. ", I'm confused:  do you mean that on line 6, the `super`'s own `__self__` attribute is annotating the instance where `super` is called?

Comment: by the way: "...it is rather a proxy object, that will rely any attribute retrieval or method call to methods and attributes on the proper superclass.... ".  Is it a typo to use the word "rely"?  you meant "relay" ?  sorry i'm not native english speaker

Comment: I still don't understand why `Meta_1` is passed to `super()` as the first argument.

Comment: The first argument to `super` is almost always the class in which the method you are defining appears, so much so that in Python 3 that's the default value if you simply call `super()`, with no arguments. (There are reasons to use a different class in the MRO, but they are rare and you really shouldn't worry about it at this time.)

Comment: The first argument to `super` serves as the starting point for the MRO search; `super(A, obj)` returns a proxy to the class *after* `A` in the MRO for object `obj`.

Comment: As fr your question on the first comment, I will clarify the text in the answer itself

Comment: @chepner I understand but that is exactly why I'm confused:  you said "`super(A, obj)`  returns a proxy to the class after `A` in the MRO for object `obj`", but in my case, the MRO for object `obj` does not contain `A`.  The MRO for `Car` does not contain `Meta_1`, you cannot find `Meta_1` in the MRO for `Car`. Right?

Comment: @jsbueno Thank you for the edit. I get that `super()` is not the actually "dad" class but it is a proxy object. What I don't get is: `super()` will look into the MRO of the second input argument to find the first input argument, and return the next class to it.  In my case, The MRO for 2nd argument, a.k.a `Car`,  does not contain the 1st input argument, a.k.a. `Meta_1`, you cannot find `Meta_1` in the MRO for `Car`.

Comment: @jsbueno quoting you: ".....When you use `super()` inside the metaclass, the class proxied is the metaclass's superclass, which is `type` ....".  I get that this is what actually happened, but I don't see how:  I thought calling `super(A, obj)` would return a proxy to the class after `A` in the MRO for `obj`. You are saying that if we call `super(A, obj)` inside the metaclass, it doesn't use the 1st and 2nd input arguments in the usual way, i.e. to proxy the class after `A` in the MRO for `obj` ?

Comment: If you call `super(A, ...)` it will, yes, create a proxy for the next superclass of A on its MRO. And that is not Meta_1 or type, but `object`. It does not care where the call is done, if inside the metaclass or not. 
But as @chepner puts it: one almost never needs to use `super` for a class in clde that is not inside the class that needs to use super itself. So much that it is the ONLY case where the Python language has special features to magically autofill the arguments in a function call.

Comment: (Even the call to methods that insert `self` is done in code that is completely customizable in Python code. The implicit parameters to  `super()` however, are created at compile time, and have no pure Python equivalent)

Comment: @Thank you for your patience, first of all. 
Could you please answer specifically to this question: "`super()` will look into the MRO of the second input argument to find the first input argument, and return the next class to it. But in my case, the MRO for 2nd argument, a.k.a `Car`, does not contain the 1st input argument, a.k.a. `Meta_1`, you cannot find `Meta_1` in the MRO for `Car`. so why would `super(Meta_1, cos)` take us to `type.__call__` ?? "

Comment: The second input argument to `super` must be an instance of the first argument. And it is the MRO of the first argument that is looked. And the MRO for `Meta_1` is `(Meta_1, type) `. The MRO for  `Car` is `(Car, object)`. As it is in the text above, the class inheritance tree has _nothing_ to do with the class inheritance tree.

Comment: If you simply do not put an explicit argument to super, as is the best practice, it will just work. Only very, very specific code should ever need to use `super` outside a subclass.

Answer (score 2):

It's important to pay attention to what values are being used as each argument to `super`. The primary purpose of `super` is to perform attribute lookup according to some method-resolution order (MRO). The second argument determines *which* MRO to use; the first determines where to *start* looking.

An MRO is always defined by a *class*; when performing method resolution on an instance, we use the MRO of the class of which that instance is a type.

In the class

```
class Meta_1(type):
    def __call__(cls, *a, **kw):             # line 1
        print("entering Meta_1.__call__()")  

        print(cls)                           # line 4
        print(cls.mro())                     # line 5
        print(super(Meta_1, cls).__self__)   # line 6

        rv = super(Meta_1, cls).__call__(*a, **kw)  # line 7
        print("exiting Meta_1.__call__()")
        return rv
```

we see two uses of `super`. Both take the same arguments. `cls` is some object passed as the first argument to `Meta_1.__call__`. That means we'll use the MRO provided by `type(cls)`, and we'll use the first class found *after* `Meta_1` that provides the desired method. (In the first call, `__self__` is an attribute of the proxy object itself, rather than an attribute or method of the class whose proxy `super` returns.)

When you run your code, you see that `cls` is bound to your `Car` type object. That's because `Car()` is implemented by `type(Car).__call__()`; since `Car` uses `Meta_1` as its metaclass, `type(Car)` is `Meta_1`.

`cls.mro()` is irrelevant, because that's the MRO used by *instances* of `cls`.

The MRO of `Meta_1` itself can be seen with

```
>>> Meta_1.mro(Meta_1)
[<class '__main__.Meta_1'>, <class 'type'>, <class 'object'>]
```

(`mro` is an instance method of the `type` class, and so requires the seemingly redundant instance of `type` as an argument. Keep in mind that `cls.mro()` is equivalent to `type(cls).mro(cls)`.)

So line 7 is a call to `type.__call__`, in order to create an instance of `cls` that `Meta_1.__call__` can return.

Comment: This answer concludes all the comments and answers of this question. Well explained!!

Comment: quick question: when you say  "....`cls` is some object passed as the first argument to `Meta_1.__call__`. That means we'll use the MRO provided by `type(cls)` .....",  here `super()` has not been called yet at line 1,  so I don't see how putting `cls` as the first argument leads us to using the MRO of `type(cls)` instead of `cls`. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

This is an excellent answer from the original post by [Michael Ekoka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/56974/michael-ekoka) where my sample code came from:
[Using the __call__ method of a metaclass instead of __new__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966772/using-the-call-method-of-a-metaclass-instead-of-new/39363704?noredirect=1#comment100012101_39363704)

Basically, I need to get a better understanding of how `super()` works.

quote:

`super` will indeed use `cls` to find the MRO, but not the way one might think. I'm guessing you thought it would do something as direct as `cls.__mro__` and find `Meta_1`. Not so, that's `Class_1`'s MRO you're resolving by doing that, a different, unrelated MRO, and `Meta_1` isn't a part of it (`Class_1` does not inherit from `Meta_1`). `cls` even having an `__mro__` property is just an accident due to it being a class. Instead, `super` will look up the class (a metaclass in our case) of `cls`, i.e. `Meta_1`, then will look up the MRO from there (i.e. `Meta_1.__mro__`).