# Selecting a subclass at instantiation in Python

Tags: python, subclass

I would like to choose a subclass at instantiation to select specific attributes from certain classes.  I've worked out the following:

**Code**

```
class Foo:
    a = "foo"

    def __init__(self, dtype=Bar):
            self.__class__ = dtype


class Bar:
    b = "bar"


class Baz(Bar):
    c = "baz"
```

**Demo**

```
Foo(dtype=Bar).b
# 'bar'

Foo(dtype=Baz).b
# 'bar'

Foo(dtype=Baz).c
# 'baz'
```

This gives the desired result, selecting specific attributes from `Bar` while optionally extending features with `Baz`.  Unlike subclassing however, we have no access to `Foo`'s attributes.

```
Foo(dtype=Baz).a
# AttributeError: 'Baz' object has no attribute 'a'
```

There are occasions when not all attributes are desired, so subclassing `Foo(Baz)` is not preferred.

What's the idiomatic analog to accomplish this in Python?

Comment: Why can't you just use inheritance? You could dynamically pick the subclass like `var = Bar; var()`.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). I don't know that doing this would ever be idiomatic.

Comment: @KentShikama Choosing `var = Bar()` still excludes attributes in `Foo`.

Comment: Per https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__ , if `__new__` returns an instance (including subclasses), `__init__` will be called. But this is all performed by `type.__call__`; see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6966772/using-the-call-method-of-a-metaclass-instead-of-new

Comment: That said, `__new__` returning a different type should be quite rare; I've only done it in FFI-related code to map `NULL` to `None`.

Comment: @pylang Can you please elaborate? `var = Bar; var().a` outputs "foo" as expected.

Comment: Note it isn't `Bar() but Bar`; you're dynamically choosing the class to instantiate.

Comment: I've posted an answer below to clarify what I am saying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why create an instance of `Foo` in the first place if you really want an instance of `Bar` or `Baz`? Instead, make `Foo` a factory for instance of `Bar` and `Baz`.

```
class Bar:
    b = "bar"

class Baz(Bar):
    c = "baz"

class Foo:
    a = "foo"

    def __new__(cls, dtype=Bar):
        return dtype()
```

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, just use plain inheritance.

```
class Foo:
    a = "foo"

class Bar(Foo):
    b = "bar"

class Baz(Foo):
    c = "baz"

# Example use
import random
class_to_instantiate = Bar if random.choice([True, False]) else Baz
print(class_to_instantiate().a)
```

Outputs

```
foo
```